# PHP: Using a class's var content in another array?

Tags: php, class

I have a PHP class which I've created a string variable ($tip in this example); Then I have a multi-dimensional array that I want to insert that $tip variable's content as a value. I'm getting a WSOD however, when I try to use either `$this->tip` or just plain `$tip` there? (see screenshot)

Reason being, I have to use the same, long, text string in multiple places, and rather than fill the class with tons of characters, I'd rather use a single var with the string and just call it where needed.

I'm not sure the problem is because I'm trying to insert it into a second array, or if I'm just doing it wrong in general?

Anyone know how I can do this?

[image]

Comment: Is this still in the class definition or in a method ?

Comment: It's still in the definition. The only thing before what is shown in the screenshot is: `<?php new [blurredout]Posts();`

Comment: Then you can't since the values in the definition cant' rely on runtime information